# Assign values to map

Tags: apex, class, list, map, territory

I have below code where i am trying to assign values to a map.

**Code**

```
List<territory> obj = database.query(soql1);
        system.debug('obj@@assign'+obj);
        Map<Id, territory> terrMap = new Map<Id,Territory>(); // [Select Id,Category_ID_abv__c,ParentTerritoryId,Name from Territory]);  // where ID not in: excludeterrId
        for(territory objCS : obj)
        terrMap.put(objCS.ID, objCS);
        system.debug('terrmap@@assign'+terrmap);
```

As from debug, i get terrmap value is populated fine with above code inside constructor. But in another method as below `[Line - system.debug('terrmap@@check'+terrmap); ]` it shows null in debug statement. What could be the reason? Please let me know.

**Method**

```
public Integer prepareInScopeUserList(Territory t, String curHierString)
    {    List<Id> childTerrs = new list<Id>();

         system.debug('userterrsIds@@Hi'+userterrsIds);
         for(Id s : terrHierTopDownMap.get(t.Id)) {
    if(userterrsIds.contains(s))
      childTerrs.add(s);
       }

      /*   if(l.contains(terrHierTopDownMap.get(t.Id)))  
         childTerrs = terrHierTopDownMap.get(t.Id);*/
        Integer childCount = 0;



        if(childTerrs == null)
            return 0;

        for(Id childTerr: childTerrs)
        { Territory nt; 
        system.debug('terrmap@@check'+terrmap);  
        if(terrmap!=null)
           { nt = terrMap.get(childTerr);
            if(!excludedNodes.contains(nt.Name) ) //&& userterrsIds.contains(childterr)
            {
                childCount ++;
                hierarchyNode hn;
                if(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr) == null && (t.Name != 'iRep'  && t.Category_ID_abv__c !='PM'))
                {
                    terrHierIdMap.put(childTerr,terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id));
                }
                else
                {
                    Integer hierId = terrHierIdMap.keySet().size()+1;
                    terrHierIdMap.put(childTerr,hierId);
                }


                Boolean userAssocTerr = False;
                if(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr) != null)
                {   //TerrUserMap.get(childTerr)  Need change here. @Saikat
                  If(resultids.contains(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr)))             
                    inScopeUsers.add(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr));     
                    hn = new hierarchyNode(terrHierIdMap.get(childTerr),terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id),'User',terrMap.get(childTerr).Name,TerrUserMap.get(childTerr));              
                    userAssocTerr = True;
                }
               else
                {
                    if((t.Name == 'iRep' && terrMap.get(childTerr).Category_ID_abv__c != 'PM') || t.Category_ID_abv__c == 'PM')
                    hn = new hierarchyNode(terrHierIdMap.get(childTerr),terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id),'Terr','<' + terrMap.get(childTerr).Name +'>',null);              
                    userAssocTerr = False;
                }

                //String hierString = curHierString + '->' + nt.Name;
                String hierString =  nt.Name;
                terrHierMap.put(nt.Id,hierString);
                Integer grandChildCount = prepareInScopeUserList(nt, hierString );
                List<hierarchyNode> hierSubList = hier[hier.size()-1];
                if(hierSubList.size() >= 1000)
                {
                    hierSubList = new List<hierarchyNode>();
                    hier.add(hierSubList);
                }
                if(grandChildCount > 0 || userAssocTerr )
                {
                    if(hn != null)
                    hierSubList.add(hn);
                }    
                else 
                    childCount --;    
            }
          }
        }   
        return childCount;     
    }
```

Please note terrmap is transient type map.

```
  Transient Map<Id,Territory> terrMap{get;set;}
```

Comment: What do you mean `terrMap` is null? Maybe empty, but the code you posted could not lead to that map being null.

Comment: Sorry Adrian. It's not null in constructor with above code. But it shows null in a method when I try to fetch that value.

Comment: You have not given us the proper context to solve your problem. I suggest a more complete example.

Comment: Where are you running that first snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You say that terrMap has the [`transient`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) keyword applied. That is likely the reason it is null after a round trip to the server.

While it was populated in the constructor, if the `prepareInScopeUserList` method was invoked via a subsequent server request the map wouldn't have been transmitted via viewstate to maintain the value.

You could either remove the `transient` keyword, or if the viewstate size is a concern, check if it is null before using it and repopulate it from the SOQL query as required.